# SQL Server, queries from different clients

Tags: sql, sql-server, express, sql-server-express

My problem is: I have 5 vba excel clients sending SQL queries to a remote server. Will they contradict? Like for ex. a table `food` contains:

```
itemId  Name
--------------
3       burger
4       pizza
```

Now if I increment the value of item id through 4-5 different clients, will there be a collision?

Comment: If you are opening a recordset in vba, you can specify which form of locking best suits you (recordset.locktype). I think you should be fine as far as concurrency goes.

Comment: Are you incrementing the ids already in the table, or are you talking about inserting new records (and thus getting new ids)?  If it's the second, SQL Server, like most RDBMSs, has an `IDENTITY` column; this is a completely threadsafe, intended for concurrent environments, autogenerating value column.  But otherwise... yes, the database is a shared resource, so you have to think about it (and work with it) as if it were a regular data object in your application language.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert table food
select 1 + max(itemId), 'spaghetti' from food
```

If you do it that way, no: 5 clients won't conflict, and neither will 5000.